# How can I scroll through div text with fixed container?

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

I have a container with a lot of text, but I want the container to remain fixed. The container doesn't hold all the text, and I want a scroll to move the text that is overflowing from the bottom into the fixed div while the text at the top of the div overflows from the top and becomes hidden.

Essentially, I want the container to be fixed, but the window scroll bar to account for the total length of the text, not just the height of the fixed container.

```
#text-container {
   position: fixed;
   height: 300px;
   width: 400px;
   background: cyan;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YEz5h/

I don't necessarily need any direct solutions, but want to be pointed in the right direction. I don't want any overflow scroll bars. I want the main window scroll bar to be able to control the movement of text into view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with a little bit of jQuery. I append an inner `div` to the `#text-container` with position relative. I then listen for when the window is scrolled and update the `bottom` css position to be the same as `scrollTop`

```
$('#text-container').wrapInner('<div></div>');
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    $('#text-container > div').css('bottom', $(window).scrollTop());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YEz5h/3/

Comment: Do you know of a way I can determine the height of the the text so I can automatically determine the height of the 'body'

Comment: Look into `scrollHeight`

Answer (score 0):

Check the JS Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/YEz5h/2/

```
#text-container {
    position: fixed;
    max-height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    background: cyan;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know I can do that, but I don't want any overflow scroll bars. I want the main window scroll bar to be able to cover the movement of text into view.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
overflow-y:auto;
overflow-x:hidden;
```